# Boto3 dynamodb query on a table with 10Gb size

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have been trying to fetch all the records on one of my `GSI` and have seen that there is a option to loop through using the `LastEvaluatedKey` in the response only if I do a scan. I did not find a better way to use `pagination` using query in `boto3`. Is it possible to paginate using a query.

import boto3
    from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
res = table.query(
    TableName='myTable',
    IndexName='my-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('myVal').eq(1)
)
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in res:

   for item in res['Items']:
       print item #returns only a subset of them
```

Comment: please provide more details of what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to query a index to fetch all the records in dynamodb table. The above code snippet is only returning few 100 records while there are millions of them. Unable to paginate using query function. i am able to paginate using scan.

Answer (score 2):

The document mentioned the limit of [boto3.dynamodb.table.query()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query) : 1MB data.

You can only use [Paginator.Query](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Query) return iterator(which make sense).

It seems you can replace your table.query with the Paginator.Query. Try it out.

Notes : 
There is a catch for boto3.resource() : not all resources services are implemented. So for the dynamodb pagination generator, this is one of those case.

```
import boto3 
dyno_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
paginator = dyno_client.get_paginator('query')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(.....)
```

Comment: Edited the code above. Have this error trace now. 
AttributeError: 'dynamodb.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_paginator'

Comment: @Zzz : when resource.() not build , blame boto3 ;-) . Actually , you can only use client, i.e.   `paginator = client.get_paginator('query')`

Comment: No luck. I tired that as well.

Comment: @Zzz what error did you get? I don't see any error when I declare paginator query class.

Comment: I have used LastEvaluatedKey and that solved for me.